# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "login" at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: javascript, node.js

**when i call api: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login**,
*i got the error like  this image.
i try to fix but i cannot
thanks*

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    const secret = process.env.secret;
    if(!user) {
        return res.status(400).send('The user not found');
    }
    if(user && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.passwordHash)) {
        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                userId: user.id,
                isAdmin: user.isAdmin
            },
            secret,
            {expiresIn : '1d'}
        )
        res.status(200).send({user: user.email , token: token}) 
    } else {
       res.status(400).send('password is wrong!');
    }
    
})
```

[image]

Comment: share few working code with github, so, to easily debug

Comment: i dont know how to use github

Comment: upload project with zip to google driver, of course, you need delete almost main code, and, I need only few data models, and configuration

Comment: thanks Bro, i fixed it successfully, the API is a method POST but i use METHOD GET, so i got error